# Is this java generics, and how can this possibly work?

Tags: java, generics

I'm looking at "WordCount", the hello world example for Hadoop, and it contains the following method:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
   public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
     throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       int sum = 0;
       for (IntWritable val : values) {
           sum += val.get();
       }
       context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

I must be misinterpreting what I am reading.  I read this asa generic class called Reduce, which extends base class Reducer, with some generic types.  Coming from C#, the signature would not be allowed, because there are two instances of Text, and the compiler would not know how to map the arguments appropriately.

Could someone explain this unfamiliar syntax?

Edit: 
This is an example of Generics, however, in this form, the actual types to be used have been set in the declaration. The class Reduce, is not generic, but Reducer is, and we have set parameters A, B, C, and D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reducer` is apparently typed as `<A, B, C, D>`. Just because A and C happen to be provided by the same type doesn't make it impossible (and should work in C# as far as I know).

Edit: to clarify -- you can have a method with more than one parameter of the same type: `public void foo(String a, String b)`. One wouldn't say this was ambiguous. Generic types are parameters on the class, and can be used in a similar fashion. Think of a `Map<String, String>` -- you may have one String that represents an ID pointing to another String as a username.

Comment: so is A substituted or C substituted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Everywhere in `Reducer` where A is referenced, the actual type `Text` will be used. The same goes for C.

Comment: Oh I got it. Maybe I'm rusty since I have been doing javascript for several months.

Answer (score 2):

The same way that you pass an argument to two method parameters, you can substitute two type parameters by a single type argument. For instance, if `Reducer` is declared as `class Reducer<A, B, C, D>`, then `Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>` is a valid type.

However, if the type parameters have different constraints, e.g., different `super` and `extends` constraints, you may not be able to use the same type argument for both type parameters.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of the question. Your answer seems to address generics but not this special case of generics.

Comment: I updated my answer to not only explain the general rule but also its application to your specific example.

Answer (score 1):

The two `Text`s refer to *different* type parameters. For instance if `Reducer` had the declaration

```
public class Reducer<A, B, C, D> {
```

then in `Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>`, the first `Text` would refer to type parameter `A` and the second to `C` - so the compiler can distinguish between them.

Comment: So in the above example, is A or C substituted?   The fact that this is ambiguous is a problem for me.

Comment: @MedicineMan All of the type parameters would be substituted with `Text`, `IntWritable`, `Text`, `IntWritable`, respectively. So `A`->`Text`, `B`->`IntWritable` etc. Is this what you're asking?